# Separating components in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a parent component that has state and a child component that uses the youtube-react api to create a video player.  The child component contains both state and methods that are used to work on the video player (e.g. event handlers).

I want to ask if should I separate out the child component by making it a stateless functional component?  I can do this by placing all the methods and state of the child in the parent component and then pass all relevant methods/data down to the child via props.

My concern with separating the child component is that will make understanding how everything works confusing.  Also, it will result in a huge parent component as the parent component already contains methods and state for other child components.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle

Don't give all the responsibility to one component
At least I would leave it to the child or even make a component that handles the player but definitely not give it to the parent who I guess already has other responsibilities

Comment: Hi, I would recommend you to look at this case from a "reusability" point of view. Imagine you will have to use `YoutubePlayer` component in other places of your web app. Will this require you to copy-paste is methods between different parent component? If yes - that its better to keep all logic related to `YoutubePlayer` inside of it.  So you may even share it on npm - and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think it all breaks down to personal preferences. I like to write components which are reusable and handle all the logic by themselves, so that I can use them as often as possible. This could result in some components get bigger then others.

I think a good starting point is here: https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html